# deal with void pointers and char in c++

Tags: c++

i am working on a piece of code right now and got a problem with void pointer and char. basically, within the serialize function, we would have a new char. we would need to store that char in `buffer`. and here is the signature of serialize function.

```
void serialize(void *buffer,
               //some other inputs here 
              ){
std::string str = "";
/*some code here, store the final output in str first*/

char* charStr = new char[str.size()];
strcpy(charStr,str.c_str());
buffer = static_cast<void*>(charStr);
}
```

using the function like this,

```
char buffer[256];
serialize(buffer, 
          //some other inputs here 
);
```

However, the data stored in `buffer` would be something real strange. I changed the void pointer in the signature to char pointer as a temporary solution. However, i know there must be a better one.

Comment: note that `strcpy` would put a null-termination character at the end of the string, which isn't counter by `str.size()` (so you would get a buffer overflow with the posted code).

Comment: You know that `buffer = ...` assignment has absolutely **no** effect on the caller's parameter, right?

Comment: I would change the type of the buffer parameter to char*.  Why use void, since it really is a pointer to raw memory (bytes)?  Otherwise, I like Zach's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fill a buffer, you cannot assign to it (that will just overwrite the pointer, leaving the original buffer contents intact). You also do not need a temporary buffer in serialize (charStr). You can directly strcpy to the output buffer, like this:

```
void serialize(void *buffer
              ){
  std::string str = "foo bar baz";
  strcpy((char *)buffer, str.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define it as

```
   void serialize(void *& buffer,
                   //some other inputs here 
                  ){
```

use pointer as parameter, remember to delete the buffer

```
char* buffer;
serialize(buffer, 
          //some other inputs here 
);
```

Comment: This option cannot be used as `char buffer[256]; serialize(buffer, ` as OP specified